# vsftpd - how to allow user to delete files added by another user/group

Tags: centos, vsftpd

I have 2 CentOS servers, A and B

A, our live server, has an instance of Apache Tomcat running, that downloads files from an external FTP server.
After it has downloaded these files, it also copies them to another folder "outbox". These files are all owned by user:group tomcat7:tomcat7, with 664 permissions.

I have installed vsftp on A, and created a user, "dev_user", whose home directory is the "outbox"

B, our dev server, has an instance of Apache Tomcat running, that downloads files from A's FTP server.

What I would like, is that once "dev_user" has completed a GET on a file, they can also issue RM on that file, and it will then be removed from "outbox"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`usermod -a -G tomcat7 dev_user`.

That will put dev_user into the secondary unix group of tomcat7, which will allow it to issue the rm command.